# Can I provide the type-checker with proofs about inductive naturals in GHC 7.6?

Tags: haskell, ghc, data-kinds

GHC 7.6.1 comes with new features for programming at the type level, including [datatype promotion](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/promotion.html). Taking the example about type-level naturals and vectors from there, I'd like to be able to write functions on vectors that rely on basic laws of arithmetic.

Unfortunately, even though the laws I want are typically easy to prove on inductive naturals by case analysis and induction, I'm doubt I can convince the type-checker of this. As a simple example, type-checking the naive reverse function below requires a proof that `n + Su Ze ~ Su n`.

Is there any way I can supply that proof, or am I really in the realm of full-blown dependent types now?

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

data Nat = Ze | Su Nat

data Vec :: * -> Nat -> * where
  Nil  :: Vec a Ze
  Cons :: a -> Vec a n -> Vec a (Su n)

type family (m :: Nat) + (n :: Nat) :: Nat

type instance Ze + n = n
type instance (Su m + n) = Su (m + n)

append :: Vec a m -> Vec a n -> Vec a (m + n)
append Nil ys = ys
append (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x (append xs ys)

rev :: Vec a n -> Vec a n
rev Nil = Nil
rev (Cons x xs) = rev xs `append` Cons x Nil
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Note: I have only type-checked (and not actually run) any of this code.)

**Approach 1**

Actually, you *can* manipulate proofs by storing them in GADTs. You'll need to turn on `ScopedTypeVariables` for this approach to work.

```
data Proof n where
    NilProof  :: Proof Ze
    ConsProof :: (n + Su Ze) ~ Su n => Proof n -> Proof (Su n)

class PlusOneIsSucc n where proof :: Proof n
instance PlusOneIsSucc Ze where proof = NilProof
instance PlusOneIsSucc n => PlusOneIsSucc (Su n) where
    proof = case proof :: Proof n of
        NilProof    -> ConsProof proof
        ConsProof _ -> ConsProof proof

rev :: PlusOneIsSucc n => Vec a n -> Vec a n
rev = go proof where
    go :: Proof n -> Vec a n -> Vec a n
    go NilProof Nil = Nil
    go (ConsProof p) (Cons x xs) = go p xs `append` Cons x Nil
```

Actually, perhaps interesting motivation for the `Proof` type above, I originally had just

```
data Proof n where Proof :: (n + Su Ze) ~ Su n => Proof n
```

But, this didn't work: GHC rightly complained that just because we know `(Su n)+1 = Su (Su n)` doesn't imply that we know `n+1 = Su n`, which is what we need to know to make the recursive call to `rev` in the `Cons` case. So I had to expand the meaning of a `Proof` to include a proof of all equalities for naturals up to and including `n` -- essentially a similar thing to the strengthening process when moving from induction to strong induction.

**Approach 2**

After a bit of reflection, I realized that it turns out the class is a bit superfluous; that makes this approach especially nice in that it doesn't require any extra extensions (even `ScopedTypeVariables`) and doesn't introduce any extra constraints to the type of `Vec`.

```
data Proof n where
    NilProof  :: Proof Ze
    ConsProof :: (n + Su Ze) ~ Su n => Proof n -> Proof (Su n)

proofFor :: Vec a n -> Proof n
proofFor Nil = NilProof
proofFor (Cons x xs) = let rec = proofFor xs in case rec of
    NilProof    -> ConsProof rec
    ConsProof _ -> ConsProof rec

rev :: Vec a n -> Vec a n
rev xs = go (proofFor xs) xs where
    go :: Proof n -> Vec a n -> Vec a n
    go NilProof Nil = Nil
    go (ConsProof p) (Cons x xs) = go p xs `append` Cons x Nil
```

**Approach 3**

Alternately, if you switch the implementation of `rev` a bit to cons the last element onto the reversed initial segment of the list, then the code can look a bit more straightforward. (This approach also requires no additional extensions.)

```
class Rev n where
    initLast :: Vec a (Su n) -> (a, Vec a n)
    rev :: Vec a n -> Vec a n

instance Rev Ze where
    initLast (Cons x xs) = (x, xs)
    rev x = x

instance Rev n => Rev (Su n) where
    initLast (Cons x xs) = case initLast xs of
        (x', xs') -> (x', Cons x xs')
    rev as = case initLast as of
        (a, as') -> Cons a (rev as')
```

**Approach 4**

Just like approach 3, but again observing that the type classes are not necessary.

```
initLast :: Vec a (Su n) -> (a, Vec a n)
initLast (Cons x xs) = case xs of
    Nil     -> (x, Nil)
    Cons {} -> case initLast xs of
        (x', xs') -> (x', Cons x xs')

rev :: Vec a n -> Vec a n
rev Nil = Nil
rev xs@(Cons {}) = case initLast xs of
    (x, xs') -> Cons x (rev xs')
```

Comment: Just in case someone doesn't have access to 7.6, approach 4 typechecks with 7.4.1 if `+` is replaced by prefix `Add` and only requires `{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}`

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't twigged that I can use the existing value to do case analysis on what the Nat is. The only downside is that each proof must be constructed at runtime and will take linear time, which could turn an overall linear algorithm into a quadratic one (in this case, naive reverse is already quadratic, of course). But I think it ought to be possible to make a whole list of proofs at once and then pass that down the underlying recursion.

Comment: PS I think the need for proofs to be checked at runtime also means that it sadly is necessary to run the programs and not just type-check them. Otherwise in more complicated examples it would be easy to accidentally write a bottom proof :-(

Comment: At this point in this discussion, it is traditional to quote Randy Pollack's dictum that "the great thing about working in strongly normalizing languages is not having to normalize things". Yes, to trust a Haskell proof it is necessary to check that it evaluates to a canonical form. That is why we don't have irrefutable patterns for GADTs. Proof components in Coq or Agda need not be retained let alone executed at run time, just because every well typed closed expression is guaranteed to have a canonical value but the choice of which value (in the case of proofs) is unimportant.

Comment: @pigworker: yeah, I was just hoping something could happen at the type-level. A bit optimistic though :-)

Comment: I believe the plan (and I know two people working on it) is to install some sort of constraint solver which will significantly increase the typechecker's willingness to consider algebraic expressions equal. This wouldn't obviate the need for proof terms for hard problems or problems in other domains, but it might knock off a lot of the common issues that come up in basic uses of numerical indexing (e.g. array bounds). Interesting times.

Comment: @pigworker: Are you able to reveal any further details about work on a smarter constraint solver?